# Foundation Not Including on Sass Grunt Compile

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower, grunt-contrib-sass

I am trying to include foundation from `bower` in my recent Wordpress project.

I am under `underscores.js` for a theme.

In the bottom of my `styles.scss`:

`@import "../../../../../src/foundation-sites/assets/foundation.scss";`

Then in my `/src/foundation-sites/assets/foundation.scss`:

```
@import ‘../scss/foundation';

@include foundation-everything;
```

where `../scss/foundation' is where my`foundation.scss` file is.

Yet still no CSS is included in the resulting compile.. only the header.

I've tried re-installing from bower, and the only changes I make are to `assets/foundation.scss`.

Even then, it seems weird to have to make changes to something in the `bower` install directory, but `assets/foundation.scss` is pointing to the wrong file.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should *not* change anything in the bower directory. Is `src` what you changed `bower_components` to?

Comment: If I don't change anything I get error that the `scss` directory cannot be found. `src` is instead of `bower_components`.

Comment: I managed to fix it by only importing the `foundation.scss` file in `scss` and including `@foundation-everything` myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by importing the `foundation.scss` file from the `scss` folder and using `@include foundation-everything` in my `style.scss`.

Comment: Good choice. I always import from the `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/` directory. In theory what you were doing with the `assets` directory should have worked, not sure what the issue was.